# jquery.ajax not working for asp:button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using the following code to get time from the server.

The btnNoP .click function returns the proper time, however  the asp:Button returns alert Error on page.

How can i successfully call a webmethod from document.ready when a asp:button is clicked?

1. ```
   <script type="text/javascript">

   function PageMethod(fn, paramArray, successFn, errorFn) 
               { 
                   var pagePath = window.location.pathname; 
                   //Create list of parameters in the form : {"paramName1":"paramValue1","paramName2":"paramValue2"} 
                   var paramList = ''; 
                   if (paramArray.length > 0) 
                   { 
                       for (var i=0; i<paramArray.length; i+=2) 
                       { 
                           if (paramList.length > 0)
                               paramList += ','; 
                           paramList += '"' + paramArray[i] + '":"' + paramArray[i+1] + '"'; 
                       } 
                   } 
                   paramList = '{' + paramList + '}';
                   alert(pagePath + "/" + fn);
                   //Call the page method 
                   $.ajax({ 
                       type: "POST", 
                       url: pagePath + "/" + fn, 
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                       data: paramList, 
                       dataType: "json", 
                       success: successFn, 
                       error: errorFn 
                   });
               } 


               function AjaxSucceeded (result)
               {
                   alert(result.d);
                   //$("#Result").text("Result : " + result.d);
               }
               function AjaxFailed (result)
               {
                   alert("Error on Page");
               }




               $(document).ready(function() {
                   $('#btnNoP').click(function() {
                       PageMethod("GetTime", [], AjaxSucceeded, AjaxFailed);
                   });

                   $('#btnNoParams').click(function() {
                       PageMethod("GetTime", [], AjaxSucceeded, AjaxFailed);
                   });             



               });

   </script>
   ```
2. ```
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

   <asp:Button ID="btnNoParams" Text="Get Time" runat="server"  />
   <input type="button" id="btnNoP" />
   ```
3. ```
   [WebMethod(true)]    
   public static string GetTime() {
       return "You called at : " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
   }
   ```

Comment: If you could show what the generated HTML for the button looks like (rather than the ASP page source), you'd probably find more people that could help because it wouldn't require knowing anything about ASP, just HTML/JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the code as below.

```
$('#btnNoParams').click(function() {
   PageMethod("GetTime", [], AjaxSucceeded, AjaxFailed);
   return false;
});
```

or

following link may helpful

http://cmsnsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-call-csharp-function-in-ajax.html

**Edit :-**
if you are using jQuery ajax, you don't need to add script manager in your page. And if you are adding script manager to page, you can directly call web method without jQuery. see the above link which describe how to access web method using JavaScript,jQuery and asp.net ajax.